# PHP Strip specific keys in array

Tags: php, arrays

How do you strip a specific word in an array?

For example:

```
$results = array (
  'date' => '22. jan.',
  'flightNumber' => 'EZY6747',
  'airline' => 'easyJet',
  'from' => 'Belfast International',
  'plannedArrival' => '18:35',
  'realArrival' => 'Estimated Arrival 18:32'
);
```

Stripping the word `"Arrival"` out of `'realArrival'` to output:

```
$results = array (
  'date' => '22. jan.',
  'flightNumber' => 'EZY6747',
  'airline' => 'easyJet',
  'from' => 'Belfast International',
  'plannedArrival' => '18:35',
  'realArrival' => 'Estimated 18:32'
);
```

I hope you understand what I'm saying.

Comment: `$results['realArrival'] = str_replace('Arrival ', '', $results['realArrival']);`

Comment: No code attempt? This is not a free coding source. Show some attempt

Comment: Also, your specs are pretty vague. Do you need to loop all values or the key is hard-coded? Can the array be multi-dimensional? Does the text need to be a full word or just a substring? How should case differences (`ARRIVAL`, `arrival`...) be handled?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you want to so something(remove Arrival) on each of the values, you can use this:

```
<?php

$results = array (
  'date' => '22. jan.',
  'flightNumber' => 'EZY6747',
  'airline' => 'easyJet',
  'from' => 'Belfast International',
  'plannedArrival' => '18:35',
  'realArrival' => 'Estimated Arrival 18:32'
);

$result2 = array_map(function($s)
{
  return str_replace('Arrival ', '', $s);

}, $results);

print_r($result2);
```